# Do I need to pass UK Border Control if I'm changing from Terminal 5 to Terminal 4 at Heathrow?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, germany, lhr

I'm an Indian national. I'm travelling from Germany to India and I have a 9 hour stop at Heathrow Airport. I have to change terminals, does this mean I have to go through UK's Border Control?

Comment: If doing a landside transfer then yes.

Comment: @DumbCoder Sure, that's essentially what "landside" means. So you're just rephrasing the question to, "Do I need to do a landside transfer to get from Heathrow T5 to T4?"

Comment: Pardon my stupidity but what is the exact difference between an airside and landside transit?

Comment: Yeah I guess that's what I'm asking: Does a change in terminal count as a landside or an airside transit? Because I will have to decide what transit visa to get based on that information.

Comment: @TanushreeBaijal: No the question is whether you _can_ transfer airside or you _need_ to go landside in order to get from one terminal to the other. It's not a question of what "counts as" what (because it's not a matter of interpretation or convention whether you're going through the immigration line or not), but whether or not there is a way to get from one terminal's transit zone to another's without going through immigration. (And if I remember correctly: yes, there is -- between all Heathrow terminals).

Comment: Is this an overnight transit?

Comment: @TanushreeBaijal It's not stupidity at all. "Airside" is the same side of the security and immigration checkpoints as the planes; "landside" is the same side of the checkpoints as the rest of the country. This is why DumbCoder's comment isn't helpful: it's just saying that you'll need to go through Border control if you need to go through Border Control.

Comment: No it's not an overnight transit I arrive and leave on the same day and don't exit the airport.

Answer (score 4):

No, you will not go through border control (unless you need to collect and recheck your luggage). I've done this many times and there are buses, airside, connecting the terminals in Heathrow. Just follow the 'Flight Connections' signage.

You will, however, go through a security screening at some point (in Terminal 4 if I recall correctly).